# Can i format the disk via vmware?

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, vmware, mapr

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 on vmware and have installed mapr single node on ubuntu.
When i want to format the disk, i get error:

```
 /opt/mapr/server/disksetup -F /tmp/disks.txt the
```

output was:

```
 2013-06-18 16:34:02,8910 ERROR Global mrconfig.cc:2411 x.x.0.0:0 InitDisk failed Device or resource busy.(16). InitDisk /dev/sda7 InitDisk resp: status 16 Disk init /dev/sda7 failed. Error 16, Device or resource busy
```

the partition(/dev/sda7) is unmounted.but i can not format the disk.
Can i format the partition when i am using vmware?
what's my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just evaluating MapR or using it for Development purposes, it's much easier to use flat files instead of formatting disks. Setup new flat file with 20GB Storage use following command:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/storagefile bs=1G count=20
```

Then you can use `/root/storagefile` as your disk:

```
$ echo "/root/storagefile" > /tmp/disks.txt
$ /opt/mapr/server/disksetup -F /tmp/disks.txt
```

More Information: http://www.mapr.com/doc/display/MapR2/Setting+Up+Disks+for+MapR